# Pass options to beamer from new class

Tags: beamer, documentclass-writing

New class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2018/01/09 A test]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{beamer}
```

LaTeX file using it:

```
\documentclass[show notes]{test}

\begin{document}
    \frame
    {
        Test
        \note{test}
    }
\end{document}
```

Does not show notes. Why?

---

Answer: Different syntax for options and `\setbeameroptions`. For the first, use `show=notes`, that is `\documentclass[notes=show]{...}`, for the second use `show notes`, that is `\setbeameroptions{show notes}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110828/134574)):

test.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2018/01/09 A test]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{pgfpages}
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{test}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
    \frame
    {
        Test
        \note{test}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake, the correct syntax for options was `notes=show`, not `show notes`.