# How to pass options from beamertheme to beamer class?

Tags: beamer, themes, class-options, option-clash

How to pass options from custom beamertheme to beamer class (and already loaded packages)?

`slides.tex`:

```
\documentclass[
  %xcolor=table,  % this option should be set in the theme!
  17pt,  % you can overwrite the theme
]{beamer}
\usetheme{minimal}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A table}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \tablehead Number \\
    One \\
    Two \\
    Three \\
    Four
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`minimal.sty`:

```
%% All these seem to have no effect:
\PassOptionsToClass{14pt}{beamer}
\PassOptionsToClass{xcolor=table}{beamer}
%% or
%\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}

%\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}  % would lead to Option clash

\newcommand{\tablehead}{\cellcolor{orange}\bfseries}
\rowcolors{2}{yellow}{white}
```

Error: `Undefined control sequence. \rowcolors`

(The question is different from [Pass options to beamer from new class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410017/pass-options-to-beamer-from-new-class), which asks for a class; I asked for a theme/package.)

Comment: Short answer: you can't. When your theme is loaded, it is too late to set beamer options, as beamer has long been loaded. You can can force a certain font size as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553421/how-can-i-load-a-standard-font-size-file-in-a-beamer-theme

Comment: And instead of the `table` option for `xcolor`, you could load the `colortbl` package