# How can I load a standard font size file in a beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, fontsize, themes

I am struggling to set a standard font size definition in my theme file. What I want to achieve is, that a user can not easily modify the font sizes, to stick to the corporate design. So my technique is to load the nearest font size definition file `size10.clo` first and then only redefine the sizes that I need to adapt. This is how I try it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%This shall be in a font theme
\makeatletter
\input{size10.clo}
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
    \@setfontsize\normalsize{9.45bp}{12.08bp}
    \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
    \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
    \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
    \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
    \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\makeatother
%%%%%%This shall be in a font theme


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course the part between the comment shall be externally in the font theme, but this illustrates the problem quite well, because whatever option beamer processed before, I will see `Command \small already defined. }` and multiple others, because `size10.clo` uses `\newcommand`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: For what purpose you want to change the font size in `beamer` document? Since `beamer` already has an hierarchical structure of font themes. For example, you can use `\setbeamerfont{<font theme>}{size={<size command>}}`.

Comment: And, depending on which font size class option is used, `beamer` will load corresponding `sizeXXX.clo` file. By defulat `11pt` is set, so `size11.clo` is loaded. To load `size10.clo`, you can use `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}`. Section 18.2.1 of `beamer` manual has a full list of available font size options.

Comment: The problem is the regular content, I need to make sure `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize` etc. match a certain size, so the content of slides is formatted correctly. Are there beamer fonts for this purpose as well?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I know that I could use `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}` but then the user can just remove the `10pt` from the options and all definitions are gone and revert to standard, or even worse he could change it to `20pt` and everything is off in size. This is why I want to hardcode a basic font size in my theme.

Comment: OK. Then you can un-define every related font size commands, for example `\let\normalsize\@undefined`, then (re)define them. To be honest, since redefining a macro is so cheap, there is hardly any hardcoding assurance in latex. (why TeX-SX ate the at to you)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ OK, that means I need to `\let` all commands from the `size10.clo` file before I load it? In that case I think it is easier to copy `size10.clo` and change all `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand`. I agree, that it is not really hardcoding, but I want to make it hard for the regular user, to redefine them "just because". In the end there is still the beamer option to `shrink`. ;-)

Comment: Yes I think you can just redefine them in your own macro file.